# What do you do when you are not sure which variable is the mediator and which is the independent?

Tags: mediation

If you have two possible predictors (X and Y) for a given dependent variable (Z) and you suspect that there might be a mediation i.e. Y mediates the relationship between X and Z. However, it is entirely plausible that X mediates the relationship between Y and Z. What do you do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to determine the order of causation statistically. You need to think carefully about X, Y, and Z and chose which one will be the mediator (if any) in your model. You can refer to the classic paper by Hill (1965) (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1898525/pdf/procrsmed00196-0010.pdf) on the criteria of causation: (1) strength, (2) consistency, (3) specificity, (4) temporality, (5) biological gradient, (6) plausibility, (7) coherence, (8) experiment, and (9) analogy. In this context, think whether these criteria support X $\rightarrow$ Y $\rightarrow$ Z or Y $\rightarrow$ X $\rightarrow$ Z relationship, and then test the mediation effect statistically.

Comment: I agree with @andreybortsov. The relationship would be determined by an interaction term that is, by definition, symmetric. The assignment of "mediator" vs "independent" variable is arbitrary and up to you.